# How can use await/async in vue mounted

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await

I am trying to use mapGetters value in my other computed property. It showing null because the preferences method not executed completed. I want to wait until the store set the getter and setter. I am tried async/await but it's not working

```
mounted() {
  this.preferences();
  this.selectedColumnsHeader;
},

methods: {
  async preferences() {
    await this.$store.dispatch('fetchPreferences');
  }
}
```

store

```
fetchPreferences({ commit }) {
  return http
    .get('/help_ticket_preferences.json')
    .then((res) => {
      commit('setPreferences', res.data.preference);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      commit('setErrorMessage', `Sorry, there was an error fetching help ticket preferences ${error.message}.`);
    });
},
```

Comment: mounted also need to be `async` and then it can `await this.preferences()` - alternatively, `this.,preferences().then(() => { ... code ... })`

Comment: i tried but it doesn't work

Comment: you tried? your code shows otherwise ... does `this.$store.dispatch()` return a Promise?

Comment: your `http.get` returns a promise, which you currently don't use

Comment: simply `return http.get.....` and then `await this.$store.dispatch` will have a Promise to await

Comment: i did but still same result

Comment: I see you've edited your code with part of the answer, but you still didn't await in `mounted`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you need to await for `this.preferences()` in `mounted`

```
async mounted() {
  await this.preferences();
  this.selectedColumnsHeader;
},
```

secondly, you need to return a Promise in `fetchPreferences`

```
fetchPreferences({ commit }) {
  return http
    .get('/help_ticket_preferences.json')
    ..... etc
```

Hoe that helps